# How to bulk reposition hundreds of photos so all the faces lay above each other perfectly?

Tags: photoshop, timelapse, self-portrait, plugin

you might have seen these videos on YouTube where people take a selfie everyday and after a few years make a time lapse video of it. I did the same except that I didn't take all the photos witht the same distance, camera or light. So if I want to make a watchable clip from it I'd have to align all the photos manually in photoshop. I look for an option, plugin for photoshop or another program that can do that for me because I now have around 500 pictures and if I think about aligning them by hand in photoshop I get disgusted by even thinking of it. Every answer is welcome, maybe I can combine them.

Comment: If it were me, I would just do it manually. At 20 seconds per adjustment, I could do 180 pictures per hour and 1000 in six hours and I could easily spend six hours trying to find a tool and another six hours trying to make it work before realizing it won’t do what I want. Of course it is not me.

Comment: I think 20 seconds per adjustment is very optimistic. Plus, hours of this work is only suitable for a robot - I don't think it's sustainable. Sounds like quite a challenge.

Comment: The only thing is that I think you could easily program an application to do that because the tools you need for that already exist. But just not combined and i am too bad in IT to program it to fit it to my purpose.

Comment: The only thing it should do, is scan where (for example my eye is) and than place all the eyes on each photo above each other. Than i can do the rest

Comment: @osullic Across 100’s of pictures it seems reasonable. Though across the first 100 it seems unlikely.  Anyway, it is the kind of job that can proceed a little at a time and the OP could have already knocked out a few since yesterday just by doing the work of starting.

Comment: @bobmacaronimcstevens I have already placed the first 220 manually. It took me 5 hours. So i am looking for a more easy way because i am too lazy to do that every year.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens Your suggestion would be a good oblique answer to OP's question. In fact, they stated, "Every answer is welcome, maybe I can combine them." Please post your suggestion as answer. Thanks.